# how to write from result out to csv file with python

Tags: export-to-excel

```
'import sys

infilename = sys.argv[1]
outfilename = sys.argv[2]

infile = open(infilename)
outfile = open(outfilename,'w')

infile = open(infilename)
outfile = open(outfilename,'w')

lst = list()
for lin in infile:
    temp = lin.split(',')
    lst.append(temp)
    lst.sort()
handle.close()

for i in range(len(lst)):
    #print ("Sublist ",lst[i])          
    for y in range(i+1):
        if y <= 0:
            for z in range(int(len(lst[0]))):               
                    outfile.write(lst[i][z],"   ",)

infile.close()
outfile.close()'
```

when the code is run it only copy's from the infile to the outfile but i only want to write to csv only the result